# Определение части речи

Tags: грамматика

Коль нет цветов среди зимы, так и грустить о них (не)надо.
Ребенок как ни в чем (не)бывало заснул неодолимым сном. Радость труда (не)сравнима ни с каким другими радостями.

Какими частями речи здесь являются бывало, надо и сравнима? Вопрос даже задать не удается.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Не надо" пишется раздельно и является предикативом, имеющим оттенок долженствования. Предикативы (слова категории состояния, безлично-предикативные слова, слова состояния, предикативные слова, предикативные наречия) — слова, обозначающие статическое состояние и выступающие в функции сказуемого (предиката) безличного предложения. https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2
2. Как ни в чем не бывало - это наречное выражение, которое является устойчивым сочетанием, поэтому выступает как единый второстепенный член - обстоятельство. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_332
3. "Не сравнима" - это отглагольное прилагательное в краткой форме.

Comment: Медвежья услуга.